# Web App not getting deployed on startup in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, xampp, war

I'm using tomcat(v7.0.56) in XAMPP(v3.2.2) to deploy my Myapp.WAR file. I'm adding context path in server.xml to deploy Myapp.war file as root webapp from webapps directory. The problem is that when I start the server for the 1st time in xampp the app does not get deployed but when I restart the server the app gets deployed correctly.

Code in server.xmlbelow "Host" tag

```
 <Context path="/" docBase="Myapp" reloadable="true"></Context>
```

Can't understand where I'm going wrong...Please help..

Comment: check docBase is full qualified path ?

Comment: Meaning?? should i specify the full path like docBase="C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps\Myapp.WAR" ??

Comment: yes it should be full path like you have specified in comment

Comment: Tried that still not working..